# Incorrect Button State with WPF Command

Tags: wpf

First, let me start off by stating that I will be more than happy to post whatever code or other information I need to in order to help resolve this issue.  Unfortunately, at this time, I am just not sure what I need to post.

I have a WPF application that uses the Microsoft Ribbon library.  I know the ribbon control has been rolled into the 4.5 framework but since I am still deploying to some XP machines, I am forced to use the 4.0 framework.  I mention this only in case there is some obscure issue with the old library.

In the application, I have a RelayCommand that is bound to one of the ribbon buttons that does not enable itself correctly (or at all for that matter).  The code that is in place to determine if the command can execute is the exact same as the code for a few other buttons.  These other buttons behave correctly.  Even worse, the behavior is correct on my machine but not on any of the other machines that I have tried it on.  It doesn't appear to be isolated to XP or Windows 7.  Even worse, I have placed a regular button in the interface that calls the CanExecute method for the command and it reports a value of True even when the button is disabled.

I am at a complete loss of where to start looking.  Perhaps someone can steer me in a direction of where to begin.

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to assist me in my desperate state.

*** EDIT ***

On a whim, I installed .NET 4.5 on the machine that was not functioning correctly as this was a glaring difference between the development (my) machine and the other machines.  To my surprise, this corrected the issue.  That said, are there updates to the .NET 4.0 framework that are applied by installing version 4.5?  As I mentioned above, I am targeting some XP machines so I cannot install 4.5.  Perhaps there are some other updates that can be installed without installing 4.5?

Comment: have you tried adding a `YourCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` in the ViewModel when you change the requirement for the button enabled state

Comment: I have not tried that.  Please see my edit above though detailing a bit of progress I have made which will likely take me down a different path.

Comment: well give it a try and see if it fixes the issue? it's a single line addition :). Shouldn't be too hard to test now is it? Not sure if .net45 has anything particularly addressing command updates. Issue with raising CanExecuteChanged explicitly is because updating the condition for CanExcute does not guarantee a refresh on all it's bound controls.

Comment: I placed the suggested call in the event handler for a button rather than where the conditions are updated for the sheer fact that there are many such places.  To make a long story short, this had no effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know then without seeing your project or being able to try something that can reproduce this. It's confusing why your having event handler's for some button's and Command's for other button's. It's too vague to guess. See if you can reproduce this in a small project(even if the issue only occurs in xp) and add it to your question so that someone can identify the issue

Comment: When you Install 4.5 It actually replaces 4.0. (See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx In Important Notes: •The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the .NET Framework 4. When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.)

Comment: To allow people help you better, Add: the code where you bind the Relay Command to that Button. The code where you declare the button that you are having problems. The code for one of the buttons that you have no problems. The code that is in place to determine if the command can execute. And I guess the version of the dll of the Ribbon.